# python setup.py --user install of data_files

Tags: python, pip, distutils

My pip package `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='pythpackage',
    version='1.0',
    scripts=['native.sh'],
    data_files=[('/etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/', ['io.nutty.terminal.json'])]
    )
```

when I do `sudo python setup.py install` it installs `io.nutty.terminal.json` in `/etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/` as expected. But when I do `python setup.py install --user` how do I make `io.nutty.terminal.json` go into directory `~/.config/chrome/NativeMessagingHosts` ?

Comment: what sort of data is in that file?  would `pkg_resources.resource_*` be a better fit?

Comment: @IfLoop I am not sure as I am a python/distutils newbie.

Comment: I could help you decide if pkg_resources is a sutiable alternative if you can share what sort of data is in that file...

Comment: @IfLoop Sorry I had not seen your comment. I got it working in a very non-standard way. Can you check [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nutty/1.0.0) and see if it can be done in a better way?